# Samba recycle bin on ubuntu 14.04 doesnt put the file in only folders

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, samba, 32-bit

When I delete something in Samba on a Windows system the file goes to recycle bin by default.

That works on the share on anywhere in that `/` filesystem but when I try the same thing on another drive say `/media/temp` like a flash drive what ever. Then it will create the folders but no file in the end.

The file system permissions

Folder I'm trying to delete from is `775`
  *recycle bin* is `777`

The part i added for my share is

```
[media]
   comment = media
   path = /media
   browseable=yes
   available=yes
   public = no
   writable = yes
   printable = no
   create mask = 0765
   vfs object = recycle 
   recycle: repository = /home/recycle/media
   recycle: touch = Yes 
   recycle: keeptree = yes
   recycle: versions = Yes
```

If you need more information just ask.

My Samba version is 4.1.11-Ubuntu

Ubuntu Server 14.04 (32-bit)